# I ran a basic logistic regression model using R, and my calculated probabilities are never less than .5 and it doesn't sound right to me.

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I'm trying to learn R and predictive modeling so I thought I'd do a logistic regression to determine probabilities of teams in my fantasy football league making the playoffs.

I have a table with data from a prior season that hasTeam Name, Total Wins, Total Losses, Points For, Points Against, and whether they made the playoffs (1 or 0). Then I run the following regression model.

See table below.

```
Team    Wins    Losses  PointsFor   PointsAgainst   Playoffs
<fctr>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
Team 1  6   1   649.4   567.3   1
Team 2  5   2   603.3   523.5   1
Team 3  5   2   603.0   491.2   1
Team 4  4   3   604.7   616.0   1
Team 5  4   3   581.2   587.9   0
Team 6  3   4   635.1   623.5   0
Team 7  3   4   626.6   619.8   0
Team 8  3   4   577.1   620.6   0
Team 9  3   4   556.5   552.4   0
Team 10 3   4   551.9   637.4   0
Team 11 3   4   517.1   515.7   1
Team 12 0   7   446.3   596.9   0
```

Then I run the model below.

```
playoff.lm <- glm( Playoffs ~ Wins + Losses + PointsFor + PointsAgainst, data = predict.2017, family = binomial(link = "logit"))
```

With the following results

```
Call:
glm(formula = Playoffs ~ Wins + Losses + PointsFor + PointsAgainst, 
    family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = predict.2017)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-1.46807  -0.22076  -0.07455   0.05830   1.44255  

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)   15.45650   20.16166   0.767    0.443
Wins           3.27222    3.04645   1.074    0.283
Losses              NA         NA      NA       NA
PointsFor     -0.01558    0.08507  -0.183    0.855
PointsAgainst -0.03203    0.06161  -0.520    0.603

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 16.3006  on 11  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  5.7816  on  8  degrees of freedom
AIC: 13.782

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 8
```

I then use predict with data from this season to estimate probabilities of teams making the playoffs.

```
playoffpredict <-  predict(playoff.lm,newdata = summary.2018, type="response")

invlogit <- function(x)
{
    1/(1+exp(-x))
}

prob <- sapply(playoffpredict, invlogit)


results <- cbind(summary.2018,prob)

results
```

The problem is my probabilities never get less than .5. This doesn't seem right.

```
Team    Wins    Losses  PointsFor   PointsAgainst   Prob of Playoff
Team 1  7   0   829.7   561.3   0.7309
Team 2  5   2   743.9   673.0   0.5522
Team 3  5   2   694.8   609.0   0.6933
Team 4  5   2   649.7   634.4   0.6897
Team 5  4   3   696.9   610.1   0.5339
Team 6  3   4   694.2   679.7   0.5002
Team 7  3   4   679.8   666.8   0.5003
Team 8  3   4   569.5   621.9   0.5072
Team 9  2   5   797.5   818.3   0.5000
Team 10 2   5   662.7   853.8   0.5000
Team 11 2   5   655.3   732.0   0.5000
Team 12 1   6   549.8   763.5   0.5000
```

I know it's pretty simple, and not a lot of data. I will add more data from prior seasons but I'm just trying to get started.

Comment: `predict(..., type = 'response')` should already give you predicted probabilities, no need to apply the inverse logit.

Comment: Since losses is equals to total games - wins, then you have some multicollinearity in your model. I recommend you drop losses, or use win percentage instead.

Comment: @Marius you should write that as an answer, noting that `invlogit(0)==0.5` and `invlogit(1)==0.7310586`

Comment: @Marius, thank you for that. I didn't realize that was the case. Then my model is even worse than I imagined because when I don't convert it the probabilities are all almost 0.

Comment: @James I will try that instead. That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly it seems that your model isn't very accurate. Your p-values are high so that you do not have any significant variable. Try combinations and log of them (for instance log(losses)) or something else. Your bad predictions may come from the poor power of your model

Comment: Which is surprising to me. I know it's a very small sample size but I'd imagine record is a really good indicator of whether a team makes the playoffs. I'm hoping adding more data will help.

Comment: Yes but do not forget for instance that record might be a good indicator but indicator does not implies a linear relation between these variables. Maybe it is non-linear? Linear regression only search for linear dependance.

Comment: Hmmm. I'll have to think about that. When I ran a pure liner regression (instead of logistic), I was getting an R^2 of above .9. Thanks.

Comment: Yes but be careful because usually an R^2 of more than 0.8 doesn't mean that your model is good but rather that there is overfitting (for instance if one class is under-represented)...